# How to select a text from table and click with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

In order page when I make a payment, I get the created payment listed in payments list page. The created payment will always list on the first row of the table. I want to know how to get a text “This is Project:
“ and also be able to click on it. Every payment has its own id in a row i.e.  Here is the snipped of the table:

```
<div id="PAYMENT-CONTAINER" style="clear:both">
<div class="list-widget" id="PAYMENT-LIST">
<ul style="visibility: visible;" class="table">
<li id="393118">
    <div class="no-expand col0" style="text-align: center; width: 31px;"><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" value="393118"></div>
    <div class="no-expand col1" style="text-align: center; width: 57px;">
        <span class="tag untagged">•••</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col2" style="text-align: center; width: 155px;">
        07/28/2015
    </div>
    <div class="col3" style="width: 401px;">
        5280 FAST PITCH
    </div>
    <div class="col4" style="width: 344px;">
        This is Project: 
    </div>
    <div class="col5" style="text-align: right; width: 213px;">
        $25.00
    </div>
    <div class="col6" style="width: 188px;">
        Stacey Smith
    </div>
    <div class="col7" style="width: 178px;">
        In Process
    </div>
</li>
<li id="393119">
    <div class="no-expand col0" style="text-align: center; width: 31px;"><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" value="393119"></div>
    <div class="no-expand col1" style="text-align: center; width: 57px;">
        <span class="tag untagged">•••</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col2" style="text-align: center; width: 155px;">
        07/28/2015
    </div>
    <div class="col3" style="width: 401px;">
        5280 FAST PITCH
    </div>
    <div class="col4" style="width: 344px;">
        Donations are for good cause
    </div>
    <div class="col5" style="text-align: right; width: 213px;">
        $26.00
    </div>
    <div class="col6" style="width: 188px;">
        Stacey Smith
    </div>
    <div class="col7" style="width: 178px;">
        In Process
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text WebElement by using below xpath:

```
//div[@class='col4']
```

or

```
 //div[contains(text(),'This is project');
```

you can use any one of the xpath to find web element.

Something like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col4']"));
//Print text
print(element.getText());
//Click on that element if it is clickable.
element.click();
```

Comment: what would be the xpath for the whole first row? For example I want to assertTrue(when the whole row has a string I pass in)?

Comment: following is the xpath for whole first row in a table:  //ul[@class='table']/li[1]

Comment: youtube series means? Do you want to test youtube video?

Answer (score 0):

Xpath selector for your case is: //div[contains(text(), 'This is Project:')]
. For example, if instance of webdriver is called like "driver", then code should be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'This is Project:')]")).click();
```

Comment: what would be the xpath for the whole first row? For example I want to assertTrue(when the whole row has a string I pass in)?

Answer (score 0):

If your required text "This is Project:" always appears in first row, then you can try below xpath:-

```
//li[1]/div[@class='col4']
```

//to get text:-
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[1]/div[@class='col4']")).getText();

//to click on it:-
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[1]/div[@class='col4']")).click();

Comment: what would be the xpath for the whole first row? For example I want to assertTrue(when the whole row has a string I pass in)?

Comment: I you need whole row xpath, following will be xpath:- //ul[@class='table']/li[1]                                                                                                                                          Change value of li -> li[2] to get second row values and so on..